# jQuery MaskedInput placeholder text repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, maskedinput

Trying to use MaskedInput plugin to format a date input form field but the placeholder text is repeated.

Using MVC 4,jQuery 3.6.3 and jQuery.maskedinput 1.3.1

I want the placeholder text to be "mm/dd/yyy"
here is the code and output
`$("#BirthDate").mask("99/99/9999", {placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy" });`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brpDI.png)

here is a better example
`$("#BirthDate").mask("99/99/9999", {placeholder: "h" });`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrAhx.png)